# Legal use of PC for business

Tags: licensing, is-x-legal

Is it legal to use my own PC for commercial purposes if the PC has Office 365 A1 for students (which doesn't permit use for commercial purposes) installed on it? I am a student and the Office 365 wouldn't be used at all when using PC for business, but it is installed on the PC that would be used for such purposes.

Comment: It might make a difference whether you are running your own business, use it for work at a place you work as an employee, or use it to deal with a business (such as register a warranty for a product you bought).

Comment: Microsoft can probably tell you how you can use their software, but not how you use the rest of your computer.

Comment: If it's a Windows PC, that is a distinction without a difference.

Answer (score 2):

You have to consult the license that you agreed to. One difficulty is that MS licenses software to educational institutions, which then sub-license to users, but the educational institution may write a "sub-optimal" license, one that doesn't simply re-package the terms of their license with MS (they may actually exclude terms or impose additional terms). They are not supposed to exclude terms, but you have no access to the MS-to-university license so that you can check that. Since the *university* can impose additional terms, it's not impossible that they would forbid business use of a device with said software installed.

On the third hand, if you directly license the software from MS, you do get to see the whole agreement, so you can just look it up.

Comment: Thank you for your response! What if Microsoft only forbids using the office commercially? Does that mean I can use rest of my PC (Windows 10) for business purposes?

Comment: Presumably, if that is what it says, and you can manage to not use those components, while conducting business.